# Will we able to creating an own pod file which source codes will not open for others?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I want to create a framework project on IOS and I would like to change it to a cocoa pod project. However, making cocoa pod documentation its commonly used for the project which source codes are open to other. I don't want my source codes to be seen by others. Is that possible?

Comment: It is. There are plenty of private frameworks out there.

Comment: Yes, I have created and Distributing my framework using CocoaPods and my source code not open for others. It just shows.h files.

Answer (score 0):

This is really not a pod question. It only depends on how you package your framework. Pod is just helping importing the framework as it.

If you package your project into a framework (.a file if I recalled correctly), then whoever imports your framework using pod will see the .a framework file under Pod folder. If you are not doing any packaging, your source code will be imported.

Comment: Yes, I have already done this thanks for share your thoughts on it.